# wxpython how to change menubar font

Tags: fonts, wxpython, menubar

I can't find a way to modify menubar font, and menubar has SetFont method but it didn't work!

```
menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
menuBar.SetFont(wx.Font(16, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD))
```

And I searched other related question, like call parent window's SetFont and it didn't work too.

Comment: The frame font is controlled by the OS. See `Appearance` `Application font`

Comment: Can you give a litter more information? like a link to point what to do. thanks

Comment: On linux Mint/Ubuntu in Menu->Control Centre->Appearance->Fonts->Application Font. On other operating systems, you're going to have to hunt it down but it will be similar.

Comment: As you said, it's mean I can't change menubar font in my progam?

Comment: That is correct, as far as I know. The idea being, one supposes, that there should be consistency of appearance for all window frames.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I need consider another way to do same work as menubar do

Comment: Take a look at `wx.lib.agw.flatmenu`.